# Why does Yocto use absolute paths in TMPDIR?

Tags: yocto

Changing the path of a Yocto environment is not a good idea, as I found out. This also explains why e.g. bitbake can be run regardless the current working directory. Absolute paths are stored in many places during the build process, even subdirectory structures are created into the `tmp` directory tree. I ended up in rebuilding from scratch - which takes a long time.

A documentation of how I tried to modify all paths:

```
find . -name *.conf -exec sed -i 's/media\/rob\/3210bcd4-49ef-473e-97a6-e4b7a2c1973e/home/g' {} +
```

This step replaces absolute paths, within many dynamic conf files (from xx/xx/linux to /home/linux - where linux was chosen for historical reasons. I could mount the partition also as /home/yocto or whatever name).

Next was deletion of subdirectory structures with the old path in the hope that the build process would recognize these deletions, and still rebuild quickly:

```
find . -name *3210bcd4-49ef-473e-97a6-e4b7a2c1973e* -exec fakeroot rm -r {} +
```

It was not recognized. Then I gave up.

---

*From a user new to Yocto, familiar with former/classic crossbuild environments based on `make menuconfig` etc.*

My question is:

- Why are absolute paths generated & used throughout `tmp` instead of treating everything as relative?

Or, asked differently:

- Why not use something like `${TOPDIR}/tmp` throughout the build configuration, instead of hardcoding the absolute path to `tmp`?